# Disk failure in LVM, One drive keeps disconnecting

Tags: linux, lvm, disk, fsck

I built a NAS with LVM running Ubuntu Desktop. It worked fine for almost two years until a disk started to fail. Initially, it would spew out a lot of errors on a boot fsck check from one drive. After doing some SATA cable shuffling, it worked fine for another 2-3 months, but now the disk fails to connect.

**4 Drive. Different sizes and Vendors**

Here is the output from `lvdisplay --maps`

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/LVMStorageGroup/nas
  LV Name                nas
  VG Name                LVMStorageGroup
  LV UUID                UNy6kV-gUjm-ecfi-Fj57-QU6k-bFiE-naEArH
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time *******, 2021-05-19 21:44:07 +0600
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                27.28 TiB
  Current LE             7152187
  Segments               4
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 1907720:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sdf
    Physical extents    0 to 1907720

  Logical extents 1907721 to 2861581:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sdd
    Physical extents    0 to 953860

  Logical extents 2861582 to 4769297:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sdc2
    Physical extents    0 to 1907715

  Logical extents 4769298 to 7152186:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sdb1
    Physical extents    0 to 2382888
```

`/dev/sdf/` is the one that's failing.

When this drive is connected to the system, this is what shows up in `dmesg`

[image]

What would be the best strategy to handle this situation? I had to connect the hard drive using a SATA to USB converter just to get the output for this post. This is the latest `fsck` check, when the drive was still working somewhat !

[image]

Comment: My guess is hardware damage. Use `smartctl` to check the drive.